# How to have multiple columns in tableview or alternative view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I would like to replicate a similar type of list view with filterable header as the following images show from coingecko and coinmarketcap ios apps:

[image]

[image]

I found a github package called Swiftdatatables that appears to do the same function, but is there a way to replicate this without using any 3rd party items?

I attempted to recreate it with a stackview as the filterable header  and a tbleview for the rows, but I do not see how it is possible to keep the tableview cell labels inline with the header columns?

My second though was they used a collectionview for the rows, but the layout feels more like a tableview? I am unsure on what the best way to create a similar view is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will most likely have used a UITableView with custom UITableView cells.

Using an XIB (nib) view to create the UI for a row and then passing the data in.

Check out [here](https://programmingwithswift.com/create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-with-swift/) and [here](https://medium.com/@kemalekren/swift-create-custom-tableview-cell-with-programmatically-in-ios-835d3880513d) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! I followed the links and now I have got it to replicate a very similar layout as the images.

Comment: @Jeremy Nice one! Good luck with your app :)